# Help needed accessing the %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto folder

Tags: windows, security

```
Z:\Users\markk\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>whoami
shunranet\markk

Z:\Users\markk\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>cacls Crypto
Z:\Users\markk\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F
                                                BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F
                                                SHUNRANET\markk:(OI)(CI)F


Z:\Users\markk\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>attrib Crypto
   S    I    Z:\Users\markk\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto

Z:\Users\markk\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>dir Crypto
 Le volume dans le lecteur Z s'appelle System
 Le numéro de série du volume est CE62-FA00

 Répertoire de Z:\Users\markk\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto

Fichier introuvable

Z:\Users\markk\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>
```

How is it possible that I have full control of this folder, but still cannot browse its contents?

**P.S.**

I need to fix it, because this is why I suspect the following command fails:

```
Z:\>MakeCert.exe -r -ss my -n "CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com" -sky signature -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -h 1 -cy authority -a sha1 -m 120
Error: Can't create the key of the subject ('JoeSoft')
Failed

Z:\>
```

And I need this command to succeed in order to debug HTTPS traffic with Fiddler.

Comment: I guess sysadmins do not visit this site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused, the files you are looking for probably exist.

The Crypto folder, as you may have noticed in your attrib command, is a system folder, this means it is not shown when using the dir command by itself.

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is E042-CE10

 Directory of C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft

01/17/2012  10:26 AM    <DIR>          Access
04/29/2010  01:49 PM    <DIR>          ActiveSync
01/12/2010  11:39 AM    <DIR>          AddIns
04/01/2010  09:44 AM    <DIR>          CLR Security Config
06/28/2010  11:10 AM    <DIR>          CLView
09/06/2011  12:24 PM    <DIR>          Communicator
01/12/2010  11:41 AM    <DIR>          Document Building Blocks
......
```

Notice that the Crypto folder is not shown, but if we do a 'dir /a' we see it.

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>dir /a
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is E042-CE10

 Directory of C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft

01/04/2012  12:58 PM    <DIR>          .
01/04/2012  12:58 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/17/2012  10:26 AM    <DIR>          Access
04/29/2010  01:49 PM    <DIR>          ActiveSync
01/12/2010  11:39 AM    <DIR>          AddIns
04/01/2010  09:44 AM    <DIR>          CLR Security Config
06/28/2010  11:10 AM    <DIR>          CLView
09/06/2011  12:24 PM    <DIR>          Communicator
09/07/2011  11:34 AM    <DIR>          Credentials
02/05/2010  08:30 AM    <DIR>          Crypto
01/12/2010  11:41 AM    <DIR>          Document Building Blocks
......
```

The same is true with the Keys and RSA folders within the Crypto folder, they are marked as System. In fact everything withing the RSA folder is marked as System.

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>attrib Crypto
   S    I    C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>attrib Crypto\RSA
   S    I    C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft>attrib Crypto\Keys
   S    I    C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys
```

Thus if you were to run dir within the Crypto folder it would show you that no files or folders exist (that are not System files) but a dir /a would show them.

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is E042-CE10

 Directory of C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto

File Not Found

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto>dir /a
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is E042-CE10

 Directory of C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto

02/05/2010  08:30 AM    <DIR>          .
02/05/2010  08:30 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/05/2010  08:30 AM    <DIR>          Keys
01/12/2010  11:18 AM    <DIR>          RSA
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  70,075,576,320 bytes free

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto>
```

I don't know what the issue is actually creating your keys, but I don't think it is a permissions issue or any other unexplained oddity. I know this is late getting to you, but it does explain what you are\were seeing.